# APS 2.0 Upselling Demo Project does not build

Tags: aps

I try to get into APS 2.0 ([apsstandard.org](https://apsstandard.org/)) and there are some demo projects. The most useful one seems to be the upselling project ([project-description](http://doc.apsstandard.org/pa/pa-demo-projects/upsell/)).

Now, whatever i try, the build process is always returning with this error:

```
schemas/contexts.schema.gen:43: Error: field '/operations/upsell/parameters/poaResources': additional properties are not allowed (keyword: "additionalProperties"; unwanted: ["items"])
```

i searched through the project and i can't find the reason for this - is there anybody out there with some serious skills in APS 2.0 who can help out? The funny thing is, also the built-in project template of the Eclipse SDK plugin has this error built-in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you get this error message when running 'aps build' command?

In this case, make sure you have the latest aps tools.
In case of using the APS IDE in Eclipse, also make sure the GA version is installed
as described at http://doc.apsstandard.org/tools/ide/setup/.

Albert

Comment: halleluja! the command line tools i had where in version 2.1.43 - now is build 2.1.82 available and with that version it builds fine now :)

Comment: but now i get a validation error when i install it in POA Sandbox, package is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4549844/upselling-1.0-1.app.zip